# How far is the distance between Mahlo Universe and Mahlo Cardinal?

Tags: lo.logic, type-theory, proof-theory

There seems to be some literature stating that Mahlo Universe[1][2] is the counterpart of Mahlo Cardinal in type theory, but I don't fully understand this point of knowledge.

More explicitly, I would like to know what condition is missing between `CIC + a Mahlo Universe` and `IZF + a Mahlo Cardinal`?

[1] Setzer, A. (2000). Extending Martin-Löf type theory by one Mahlo-universe. Archive for Mathematical Logic, 39(3), 155-181.

[2] Kahle, R., & Setzer, A. (2010). An extended predicative definition of the Mahlo universe. Ways of Proof Theory. De Gruyter. doi, 10(9783110324907), 315.

Comment: Can you define (and give references for the definitions) the Mahlo Universe?

Comment: @J..yB..y I'm talking about Anton Setzer's Mahlo Universe. References have been added.

Comment: Already a bit painful is the fact that the CIC <-> IZF relationship is not entirely trivial. I think things get easier when considering CIC + EM vs ZF.

Comment: @cody I would welcome this if it would alleviate your distress. The key to this question is the combination of the universe and the cardinal pair, not CIC and IZF.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure that the Mahlo-ness washes out the difference in foundation (maybe it does). What result would you like/expect to prove?

Comment: @cody just consistency strength about `CIC + a Mahlo Universe`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's awkward to ask yourself questions, but...

Rathjen, M. (2003). Realizing Mahlo set theory in type theory. Archive for Mathematical Logic, 42(1), 89-101.

The chapter 5, "Realizing set theory in Mahlo type theory" is the required construction for `CZF + Mahlo Cardinal`. The previous section shows why this construction does satisfy the definition of Mahlo Cardinal.

Comment: Neat! Ideally detailing the construction in a few words here would be really useful for future reference.